Inequality between the coefficients of complex polynomials
Let $P(z)=a_nz^n+\dots+a_0$ and $Q(z)=b_mz^m+\dots+b_0$ be polynomials with complex coefficients with $n<m$. Assume all the roots of $Q$ lie in the unit disk and that $|P|≤|Q|$ on the unit circle. Is it true that $|a_n|≤|b_m|−|b_0|$?
From the maximum principle applied to $\frac{z^{m - n}P}{Q}$ outside of the unit disk, it is clear that $|a_n|≤|b_m|$. However, it is not obvious to me what effect $b_0$ has, or how to even involve it in the inequality.

Yes. At first, we may assume that all roots of $Q$ are strictly inside the unit disk (otherwise, $P/Q$ is a rational function not exceeding 1 in absolute value on the unit circle. Therefore, $P/Q$ is bounded by $\rho_1$, which is almost 1, on the circle $|z|=\rho$, where $\rho>1$ is close enough to 1. Then we may consider the polynomials $Q(\rho z)$ instead of $Q$ and $P(\rho z)/\rho_1$ instead of $P$, and pass to the limit.)
Assume the contrary: $|a_n|>|b_m|-|b_0|$. Choose a positive number $t<1$ such that $t|a_n|=|b_m|-|b_0|$ and a number $w$ on the unit circle such that $a_n$ and $wb_n$ have the same argument. Apply Rouchet theorem for polynomials $Q$ and $twz^{m-n}P$ on the unit circle. It yields that $R:=Q-twz^{m-n}P$ has $m$ roots in the unit disk, but the product of its roots has absolute value $$\frac{|b_0|}{|b_m-twa_n|}=\frac{|b_0|}{||b_m|-t|a_n||}=1. $$
